# Incorrect number of rows returned by JOIN query in Python script

Tags: python, join, sqlite

I wrote the following code in Python that connects to DB, creates two tables and joins them. Then it prints the result of the `JOIN` query.

The problem is that the number of rows is 3, though I expected to get 2 rows. Also, if I run the same query in a command prompt using `sqlite>`, then the number of rows returned by the `JOIN` is correct, i.e. 2.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import pandas as pd

# Connecting to the database. The `connect()` method returns a connection object.
con = lite.connect('getting_started.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weather")

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE cities (name text, state text)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE weather (city text, year integer, warm_month text, cold_month text, average_high integer)")

    # Filling 'cities' with the data
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Washington', 'DC')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Houston', 'TX')")

    # Filling 'weather' with the data
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Washington', 2013, 'July', 'January', 59)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Houston', 2013, 'July', 'January', 62)")

    # Joining data together
    sql = "SELECT name, state, year, warm_month, cold_month FROM cities " \
          "INNER JOIN weather " \
          "ON name = city"
    cur.execute(sql)

rows = cur.fetchall()
cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

# Loading data into pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print("City: {0}, The warmest month: {1}".format(row['name'],row['warm_month']))
```

In Python the result is:

```
City: Washington, The warmest month: July
City: Washington, The warmest month: July
City: Houston, The warmest month: July
```

However, in command prompt the result is different (correct):

```
City: Washington, The warmest month: July
City: Houston, The warmest month: July
```

Comment: Can you show us the 3 rows it returns? E.g. `print(rows)`

Comment: @Tom Dalton: I updated the post, pls check it.

Comment: One thing I notice is that the `rows = cur....` line is outside of the `with con:` context manager. I don't think that should make a difference but probably worth fixing anyway.

Comment: Also, can you actually `print(rows)`, as well as your original output? I am trying to see if the error is in the pandas stuff.

Comment: @Tom Dalton: Putting rows=cur... inside the with solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've expanded the above in a proper answer below. Glad it's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `rows = cur.fetchall()` is outside the `con` connection context manager, so something odd is happening when you use the cursor and it's DB connection has been closed.

Ref the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager it suggests that the `with con:` provides a transaction, which might explain the strange behaviour executing the statement in the transaction but then trying to use a cursor on the result set outside of the transaction.

It still seems odd to me and I would have expected that this use would have caused sqllite3 to raise an exception telling you this was happening.